# Angular UI-Grid Conditional Cell Template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angular-ui-select

I have a cell template that displays data from an external ui-select. However I only want the cell template to appear if the row(s) is/are selected. Here is my current code:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
  { name: 'resourceChannel', 
    cellTemplate: '<div ng-if="$(\'.ui-grid-row\').hasClass(\'ui-grid-row-selected\')">{{grid.appScope.channel.selected.channel}}</div>'},
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add something like a Row-Selected-Listener and ng-if - check if the current row is in the selection.

I added a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5KoAlvxNf7BUy37pEAsD) that demonstrates a possiblity of show/hide cellTemplate.

First you add an ng-click to the ui-grid rowtemplate, f.e. addRowtoSelection().

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/uiGridViewport',
  ...
  "<div ng-repeat=\"(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index\"" +
  "ng-click=\"grid.appScope.addRowtoSelection(row)\"" +
  ...
);
```

Then you add that function to your appScope.

```
all.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [
            {field: 'firstName', cellTemplate: '<div ng-if="grid.appScope.isRowSelected(row.uid)">something</div>'},
            {field: 'lastName'},
            {field: 'company'},
            {field: 'employed'}
        ],
        ...,    
        appScopeProvider : {
            addRowtoSelection : function(row) {
                var contains = false;
                for (var i = 0, len = all.rowsSelectedIds.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if(all.rowsSelectedIds[i] === row.uid) {
                        all.rowsSelectedIds.splice(i, 1);
                        contains = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!contains) {
                    all.rowsSelectedIds.push(row.uid);
                }
            },
            isRowSelected : function(id) {
                for (var i = 0, len = all.rowsSelectedIds.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if(all.rowsSelectedIds[i] === id) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            },
        },
```

I also added a check for already selected row-IDs so you add/remove on click. In ColumnDefs you can see the reference to the isRowSelected() check, where you pass in the row.uid. That parses the current array and returns true or false.

Comment: This works but is it possible to keep the first name in the column visible until the user has selected another value? You have firstName defined in your example data array however the column is empty until the user clicks in the cell. I also found these in the ui-grid documentation        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row){
              //some function here
            });
            //gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChangedBatch($scope, callbackFunction);
        },

Comment: Never mind, I got it [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eAiR2O?p=preview). Thanks for the help.